# Wacom Cintiq tablet issues in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet

When I want to draw on my wacom cintiq 13 tablet, the cursor stays at my main display (Asus) and won't move over to the tablet. It registers the pen on the tablet, and can move the cursor. But the cursor stays on the main display all the time. This makes it so that I can't draw anything on the wacom. Only way I can draw something is to mirror the screens. I have tried the latest drivers, without any luck.

Comment: Did you try the "Map to Monitor" button in the Wacom Control Panel?

Comment: Can't find wacom control panel or map to monitor